# Webscraping amazon using requests and xpath

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

When you go into amazon there are multiple sellers available with various prices I can scrape the price shown on the page but not the price of other sellers.
Underneath the Buy Now and Add list there is a button saying " New(x)from " if you click that all other sellers show up and I want to scrape their prices, but when I enter their price XPath it gives me an error

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Panini-Sticker-Collection- 
x50Packs/dp/B08V8CF748? 
ref_=Oct_DLandingS_D_7a870443_60&smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE'


def GetPrice(URL):
    s = HTMLSession()
    r = s.get(url)

    product = {
       'price':r.html.xpath('//*[@id="aod-price-1"]/span/span[2]' )

       }

   print(product)
   return product




GetPrice('https://www.amazon.co.uk/Colgate-Fresh-Cooling-Crystals-Toothpaste/dp/B073V1MB17/ref=sr_1_5_mod_primary_new?dchild=1&keywords=Toothpaste&qid=1625698678&rdc=1&sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D&sr=8-5')
```

Comment: First thing first, please make clean your code, and post it here, which doesn't gives us unnecessary errors, like  indentation and other things. Please edit your question, and give us more detailed example that you want to scrape this things from this site.

Comment: the codes have been edited mostly indentation new to stack overflow so don't know how it lays things out also, what I'm looking for is stated in my question

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, try to use browser Developer Tools and check how the requests are loaded when any event is fired up and then try to replicate the same behaviour through your code.

Code

```
import requests
from lxml import html

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.amazon.co.uk',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'rtt': '100',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0',
    'accept': 'text/html,*/*',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'downlink': '8.4',
    'ect': '4g',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Colgate-Fresh-Cooling-Crystals-Toothpaste/dp/B073V1MB17/ref=sr_1_5_mod_primary_new?dchild=1&keywords=Toothpaste&qid=1625698678&rdc=1&sbo=RZvfv%2F%2FHxDF%2BO5021pAnSA%3D%3D&sr=8-5',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'session-id=260-4106472-8409244; i18n-prefs=GBP; ubid-acbuk=260-0481762-4830301; session-token="jc9/khgoELjvvnVyfyUE0zuV+IqwaxQgEelGbV4ihI0VtbHOyZRfQgTpdo7j85y9QuCH+19fCvnLDgNhdjtSrMCWh4U1Pct/A53U0ylVSUCMLNa4HHZqV6q/VBo8EIf0KSIkY47ClNUgwWLkZxzHkm5GWvqvqYBBl7wXIR9zKxY9x0WhN1KrWagXd8Ud062lFMG+ThXyKi0JTHk2K14qmEbPRjE2tmDCZbANgBgXvq4GAXYK/qamSGtiwHIL88aOcKL+4xjmV0o="; csm-hit=adb:adblk_yes&t:1625843678136&tb:s-HPFR45XZN4E5FMK5EH5M|1625843675264; session-id-time=2082758401l',
}

params = (
    ('asin', 'B073V1MB17'),
    ('m', ''),
    ('qid', '1625698678'),
    ('smid', ''),
    ('sourcecustomerorglistid', ''),
    ('sourcecustomerorglistitemid', ''),
    ('sr', '8-5'),
    ('pc', 'dp'),
)
s = requests.Session()

response = s.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aod/ajax/ref=dp_aod_NEW_mbc', headers=headers,params=params)

tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

prices = tree.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"a-offscreen")]')

for price in prices[1:]:
    print(price.text)
```

**output**

```
Â£1.87
Â£2.04
Â£1.44
```

Comment: Hiya could you explain what you did and how to modify it for my browser thank you :), I don't understand why the headers need to be stated or pararms

Comment: returns with a []

Comment: Using browser tools go to Network tab and then XHR, reload the page and see how request are loaded. Headers carry meta info, parameters carry actual data which is required for this case to make successful request and get desired response.

Comment: @Meh., For me it's returning all price value. Can you tell me how are you executing this code. Check the output above.

Comment: Is there a way this would work without headers or params, ie input the URL and it takes that input and scrapes it,  I'm getting the same output now however there are 9 other sellers with the same product and only outputs 3, I'm new to using web scrapers so sorry for any dum questions

Comment: I think to make successful request you have to pass headers and params using this way. Other way is to use the headless browser (like Selenium), click on the link  "New(x)from" and then render the page. Moreover, the url which you have passed in GetPrice function contains only 3 different price so I am not sure why are you saying 9. Check the URL and let me know if it contains more than 3 prices.

Comment: this is what i see, so is there no way to go around this?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt4a9.png, this is what I see.

Comment: hmm is there a way to go around the params to show my results